# missing data in pandas profiling report

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, pandas-profiling

I am using Python 2.7 and Pandas Profiling to generate a report out of a dataframe. Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling

# the actual dataset is very large, just providing the two elements of the list 
data = [{'polarity': 0.0, 'name': u'danesh bhopi', 'sentiment': 'Neutral', 'tweet_id': 1049952424818020353, 'original_tweet_id': 1049952424818020353, 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-10-10 14:18:59'), 'tweet_text': u"Wouldn't mind aus 120 all-out but before that would like to see a Finch \U0001f4af #PakVAus #AUSvPAK", 'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', 'location': u'pune', 'retweet_count': 0, 'geo': '', 'favorite_count': 0, 'screen_name': u'DaneshBhope'}, {'polarity': 1.0, 'name': u'kamal Kishor parihar', 'sentiment': 'Positive', 'tweet_id': 1049952403980775425, 'original_tweet_id': 1049952403980775425, 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-10-10 14:18:54'), 'tweet_text': u'@the_summer_game What you and Australia think\nPlay for\n win \nDraw\n or....! #PakvAus', 'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', 'location': u'chembur Mumbai ', 'retweet_count': 0, 'geo': '', 'favorite_count': 0, 'screen_name': u'kaluparihar1'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data) #data is a python list containing python dictionaries
pfr = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
pfr.to_file("df_report.html")
```

The screenshot of the part of the df_report.html file is below:[image]

As you can see in the image, the Unique(%) field in all the variables is 0.0 although the columns have unique values.

Apart from this, the chart in the 'location' variable is broken. There is no bar for the values 22, 15, 4 and the only bar is for the maximum value only. This is happening in all the variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with the sample you have provided. python `2.7.15`, pandas `0.23.4` and pandas-profiling `1.4.1`